# An exercise related to Krull topology - showing that two bases define the same topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, galois-theory

The following is a definition from my lecture notes:

> Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension with $G=Gal(L/K)$ then the family
>   subgroups $Gal(L/L_{i})$, where $L_{i}$ runs over all finite
>   subextensions, is a basis for the neighborhoods of $1$.

And the following exercise is:

> Prove it suffices to take $L_{i}/K$ finite Galois subextensions.

I am having difficulties with this exercise:

I took a basic neighborhood of $1$ - $Gal(L/L_{i})$ and I wanted
to prove that it is open in the topology defined in the exercise.
But I'm really confused because elements in $Gal(L/L_{i})$ fix $L_{i}$
and elements in $L_{i}/K$ don't fix all of $L_{i}$ expect for the
identity map.

Can someone guide me through the exercise ?

Comment: If E is any finite subextension then there exists a finite subextension F such that F/K is galois and clearly Gal(L/F) \subset Gal(L/E) and Gal(L/F) is open by definition. Thus the set Gal(L/L_i) such that L_i/K is galois forms a basis for the topology.

Comment: @random123 - Could please you add some details ?

Comment: If $M\subseteq L$ is any finite extension of $K$, then there is an extension $F\subseteq L$ such that $M\subseteq F$, $[F:K]<\infty$, and $F/K$ is Galois.Then $Gal(L/M)$ is a union of (finitely many) cosets of $Gal(L/F)$. So if $Gal(L/F)$ is open, so is $Gal(L/M)$. The group $Gal(F/K)$ is not interesting at all for the purposes of this exercise.